# Ionic2 & Angular2 $http POST request

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm currently trying to post some data to an external PHP file.

**Issue:**

**Recieving Log Error:** SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Data Parameters not posting as headers.

**What I'm trying to accomplish**

Push username to API and get a JSON response with data to push to HTML table.

**My code**

```
.controller('listController', ['$scope','$http', function($scope,    
$http){

  console.log("HTTP request initialized.");


      var request = $http({
        method: "post",
        url:"http://test.com/user/projects.php",
        data: {
            username: "jimmie",
        },
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    });

    console.log(request);

    /* Response:  */
    request.success(function (data) {
        console.log(data); // outputs **Recieving Log Error:** Above 
    });
}])
```

**Question**

I'm using this method in app.js so the HTML can use ng-controller requests to call the method on start of the app. Since I've researched this issue for a while, and found lots of discrete issues in Angular 2 mostly, but the code is completely different, and not using the $http requests, as well not using .controller with $scope's.

Can I approach this issue in an simpler way? Since the application will mostly only be built with GET and POST requests.

**GET Request**

I tried a GET request on my own API, just to check wether it's an outdated module I'm using, but the GET worked, but method: post with data won't.

**Thanks, Jimmie.**

=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your post method accept an object rather than string

```
var obj = {
     username: "test"
 }
var request = $http({
        method: "post",
        url:"http://test.com/user/projects.php",
        data: obj,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    });
```

Comment: Didn't change anything :/

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately.. Sometimes impossible to find right syntaxes since Angular and other frameworks change their syntaxes and modules each month :P

Comment: Oh. The format is in Json only, that's the error refer to, otherwise it cannot  be accepted. Can you refer to my updated answer again, username shouldnt be wrapped in double quote, just username only not "username" .

Comment: Okay, so I tried:

      var obj = {
        username: "jimmie"
      };......

In my PHP file i just wrote : echo $_POST['username'];

But it returned nothing, so I believe the params is still not being sent.

Comment: Oh.  When sending json object to the PHP file you cannot using POST, just use decode. For eg: $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')).

Comment: and then get the username properties by $data->username.

Comment: Okay, so I tried that.. Still nothing returned.. Still believe that the headers are not being sent or smthing.

http://pastebin.com/kJcqgW1G

Comment: Hang on.. Got a response now. Gonna look where it comes from. Sec. 

=))

Comment: You know what.. This string:

  $_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

Actually made the POST requests handling working. By echoing out $_POST['username'], I get the "test" name back to the Application.. 

Gonna check your answer as solution, and update the question with the solution.

Thanks a lot man!